# How can we Get Child Data Object by its ID (PrimaryKey)?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, datanucleus

I am trying to create a simple to-do API service via App Engine. I have `User` data objects that have a set of `Project` data objects and these `Project` data objects have a set of `Task` objects. The following code should give you some idea about their implementation and relationships.

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class User implements Serializable {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Persistent(mappedBy = "user")
 private List<Project> projects;
}


@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Project implements Serializable {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key id;

 @Persistent
 private User user;

 @Persistent(mappedBy = "project")
 private List<Task> tasks;
}


@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Task implements Serializable {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key id;

 @Persistent
 private Project project;
}
```

What I am doing with User data object is the following (`EntityManager` is defined as it is shown on App Engine help pages):

```
EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
try {
 User dev = em.find(User.class, id);
 em.remove(dev);
} finally {
 em.close();
}
```

What I want to do is to get `Project` and `Task` data objects by their id/Key, which is some long number that corresponds to the data object not the key combination with its parent that refers to the object as well. Since these objects are child of others, I could't figure out how to get them by their id value.

Answer (score 0):

GAE doest not support:

> Owned many-to-many relationships.

and

> "Join" queries. You cannot use a field of a child entity in a filter
>   when performing a query on the parent kind. Note that you can test the
>   parent's relationship field directly in a query using a key.

so I would suggest you change you object model, to use the long ids directly in user object for projectlist, and in project object for tasklist and user

or what I would suggest use the datastore api directly, because then you know how your data is stored, how you can get it and:  **you will design you data for GAE**.
and with datastore api you can use [Ancestor Paths](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Ancestor_Paths)

Comment: The relationships above are one-to-many (`User` has `Project`s, `Project` has `Task`s). Plus, I am not looking for a join query. I just need a way to get a child object by its id/Key.